# NextJS 13 - Server Action variables from parent function not available

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I've created a NodeJS module that I'm integrating into my NextJS 13 route. However, I've encountered a challenge with passing variables from the module to my RegisterPage component without exposing them to the client. Here's the relevant code snippet for context:

```js
export default async function MyPage({ prisma, texts } : MyPageProps) {
    "use server"

    const test = "Hello"

    const fun1 = async () => {
        "use server";

        console.log(test) // This is undefined
    }

    const fun2 = async () => {
        console.log(test) // This is defined, but i cannot pass it into the client page.
    }

    fun1()
    fun2()

    return <RegisterPage registerFunc={fun1} />
}
```

The challenge arises when executing fun1(), which results in the test variable being undefined. On the other hand, executing fun2() (without the "use server" directive) successfully defines the variable, but I'm facing difficulty in passing it to the RegisterPage component due to the asynchronous nature of server actions and the use of the "use server" attribute.

I'm seeking assistance regarding whether this is an error in my approach or if there's an alternative method to achieve my goal of passing these variables to the RegisterPage component without exposing them to the client.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why this is happening to you is because server functions cannot access the components scope (probably because they are deployed on the edge somewhere else), therefore the variable you try to access is undefined. Here is what you should do instead:

```
export default async function MyPage() {
  const myServerFunc = async (filters?: string) => {
    "use server";
    const myResult = await getDBResult(filters);
    return myResult;
  }

  return <MyClientComponent myServerFunc={myServerFunc} />;
}
```

In the example above we have defined a server action called `myServerFunc`, this function receives a set of filters in form of a string from the client and passes them to some function accessing the database.

- Database access credentials and request remains on the server.
- Access to selected filters from the client via user interactivity.

Inside your client component you could then call this function via the prop it was passed by providing it with filters you may store in your client component state.

```
"use client";

interface Props {
  myServerFunc: (filters?: string) => Promise<any[]>; 
}

export default function MyClientComponent(props: Props) {
  const { myServerFunc } = props;

  const [filters, setFilters] = useState("");

  const onClick = () => {
    const results = await myServerFunc(filters);
    console.log(results); // will show the database results
  }

  // ...
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but the Problem is, my functions are stored in a subdirectory outside from nextjs and are imported over a nodejs module. So i dont have all necessary variables. How can i pass variables to the function?

Comment: @LeonSchwanitz I don't quite understand, you can wrap the function from the module in a server action that receives parameters and pass them to your function?